# CertificateError: hostname 'proxy.iiit.ac.in' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', 'docs.python.org

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

The exact error which I get is

> CertificateError: hostname 'proxy.iiit.ac.in' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'bugs.python.org', 'wiki.python.org', 'hg.python.org', 'mail.python.org', 'pypi.python.org', 'packaging.python.org', 'login.python.org', 'discuss.python.org', 'us.pycon.org', 'pypi.io', 'docs.pypi.io', 'pypi.org', 'docs.pypi.org', 'donate.pypi.org'

I tried uninstalling python, pip and reinstalling them but that didn't resolve the issue.

When I try to install any package in a virtual environment by using sudo, I get no error but if I try `pip install <package-name>` it shows the above error.

Comment: Set environment proxy variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Comment: Ya I tried setting proxy but I still got same error